# How to check if the Network connection is Full Duplex or Half Duplex

Tags: c#, winforms, network-interface

I am trying to display in my C# Winforms application if the Ethernet connection is a Full Duplex or Half Duplex. I am not sure if we have any API to check for this. I have been using the below code to get the NetworkInterfaces

```
NetworkInterface[] adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
 foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in adapters)
        {
            IPInterfaceProperties properties = adapter.GetIPProperties();
            IPv4InterfaceStatistics stats = adapter.GetIPv4Statistics();
            Console.WriteLine(adapter.Description);
            Console.WriteLine("Speed .....: {0}",adapter.Speed);                    
        }
```

The above code gives me adapter descriptions, speed, NetworkInterfaceType, OperationalStatus etc. What I am looking to find is whether the connection is a Full Duplex or Half Duplex.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //string deviceName = "TP-Link Wireless N PCI Express Adapter";

            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\ROOT\\StandardCimv2");

            ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery($"SELECT * FROM MSFT_NetAdapter");// WHERE DriverDescription = \"{deviceName}\"");

            using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
            {
                using (ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get())
                {
                    foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{m["DriverDescription"]} : {m["FullDuplex"]}");
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vladimir. I tried the above code and I get a run time exception of "Invalid Namespace" and below is the exception details 
   System.Management.ThreadDispatch.Start()
   at System.Management.ManagementScope.Initialize()
   at System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher.Initialize()
   at System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher.Get()

Comment: I also did look at if WMI service is up and running. Seems its running without any issues.

Comment: @Baba it works well on my Win10 Pro x64 on both x86 and x64 project Build configurations

Comment: `StandardCimv2` and `MSFT_NetAdapter` are available in Windows 8 and Windows 10 only. You can find these vendor-specific informations in the registry.

Comment: I am running on Windows 7 and I guess it is civm2 instead of StandardCimv2. Should the query be different for Windows 7 machine?

Comment: Thinking cimv2 is the correct one, I tried to use  ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\root\\cimv2"); and this time it throws an "Invalid Class" exception.

Comment: @Baba it seems there is no way to get info you need using OS utils\tools\API on Win7...

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/165477-how-can-i-see-whether-i-am-connected-at-full-or-half-duplex